# Missing declaration for object definition (Rule MisraC2012-8.4)

Tags: c, misra

I try to understand what to do with this error: 
required: Missing declaration for object definition [hi] (Rule MisraC2012-8.4)

My code is:

```
typedef struct {
    int l;
} some_struct;

some_struct hi = {
    5
};

int main(void) {
    return(0);
}
```

static solve this issue but I need to use this variable as extern from another file.

Comment: I'm talking about the MISRA-C violation

Comment: It's compile fine it is just not passing the auto check for MISRA C compliens

Comment: Is all of this in one single C file or several?

Comment: If you are using them from another file, `some_struct` and `hi` should be declared in a shared header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule 8.4 is regarding type incompatibility of objects with external linkage. There's a possible severe bug that the rule aims to prevent from: declaring the object as one type in one file, then define it as another type in another file.

To prevent such bugs, MISRA therefore requires that a previous `extern` declaration of the object is visible to the file that contains the definition.

So if you aim to have `some_struct hi` defined at file scope, you must add a declaration somewhere too, preferably in a header file:

```
extern some_struct hi;
```

`static` solves the problem because then you no longer have external linkage and the rule does not apply then.

Please note that (non-const) `extern` spaghetti globals are highly discouraged in any form of program, MISRA or no MISRA. In the vast majority of possible cases, the presence of such global variables in a program is caused by bad program design.